# How to keep a uniform size of the brackets in an equation?

Tags: equations, split

I am new to latex. I have to type a very long equation in my document. I try the following and it produces the long equation but I cannot **produce the same size bracket**.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eqn_3.12}
\begin{split}
    Q=at_d\left(1+\frac{m}{2}t_d\right)-a\left(T-\delta \frac{T^2}{2}\right)+a\left[t_1-\delta \left(Tt_1-\frac{t_1^2}  
    {2}\right)\right]+ae^{mt_d} \left[(t_1-t_d)+\right. \\
    \left. \frac{\theta}{6}(t_1^3-t_d^3)+\frac{m}{2}(t_1^2-t_d^2)+\frac{\theta}{2}t_d^2(t_d-t_1)+\frac{\theta m}{4} 
    t_d^2(t_d^2-t_1^2)+\right. \\
    \left. mt_d(t_1-t_d)+\frac{\theta m}{6}t_d(t_1^3-t_d^3) \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Output**.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend that you rewrite the equation so that the fraction expressions take up much less vertical space. That way, it's no longer necessary to enlarge most of the parentheses; only one pair of parentheses -- for which I would use curly braces, mostly to provide a bit more visual contrast -- needs to be enlarged. Since the `\{` and `\}` occur on different lines, it's necessary to use explicit sizing instructions. I recommend `\Bigl\{` and `\Bigr\}`.

In the following screenshot, observe that (a) only the numerals 2, 4, and 6 appear in the denominator terms and (b) `\tfrac` is used instead of `\frac`. And, do note the use of `&` alignment points to structure the appearance of the three rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eqn_3.12}
\begin{split}
Q &= at_d(1+\tfrac{1}{2}mt_d)
     -a(T-\tfrac{1}{2}\delta T^2)
     +a[t_1-\delta (Tt_1-\tfrac{1}{2}t_1^2)] \\
  &\quad+ae^{mt_d} \Bigl\{(t_1-t_d) 
        +\tfrac{1}{6}\theta(t_1^3-t_d^3)
        +\tfrac{1}{2}m(t_1^2-t_d^2)
        +\tfrac{1}{2}\theta t_d^2(t_d-t_1) \\
 &\quad +\tfrac{1}{4}\theta m t_d^2(t_d^2-t_1^2) 
        + mt_d(t_1-t_d)
        +\tfrac{1}{6}\theta mt_d(t_1^3-t_d^3) \Bigr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```